# How to Sum text values like numbers in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

[image]

How can I translate text values into numbers and sum the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some solution now.

**SOLUTION 1**

Use "COUNTIF" function to find the number of cells that match the given text values and then multiply with the reference numbers.

[image]

**SOLUTION 2**

Use Cell "Data Format"

1. Select some Cell
2. At the Format Panel > Cell > Data Format
3. Create a Custom Format.
4. Select type as "Number"
5. Add some Rule that you want to format number as text.
6. Done! You can sum text values like a number now.

[image]

You can also see [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7706526) if you want to use a pop-up menu